# How do API consumers know the total amount of data for pagination?

Tags: api, rest, pagination

I know how to paginate data via API endpoints. So consumers can send optional parameters like `skip` and `take` and the backend responds with the desired data.

But how does the client get to know about the total amount of data so it can display *n* pages users can click on?

- do backend endpoints return additional information in fetch requests like

.

```
{
  "data": [], // contains fetched items
  "total": 123 // maximum items in database
}
```

- do backends provide equivalent endpoints ( same request payload ) but don't return the data but the total amount instead? So clients must consume this endpoint first.
- do clients ask for *n* + 1 items so if the user expects 5 items per page and the backend returns 6 items the client knows there will be a next page?

Or are there any other approaches I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Backend endpoint should provide the total number of records. Idealy no way the client would know the total number of records without the backend sending the total record count.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint should return the total count along with the data response.
You can take it a step further by saying if the records pagination has next page or previous page. This is more useful if your endpoint is consumed by a service. the payload will look like

```
{
   "data": [],
   "total": 120,
   "hasPrevious: false //this will be false if the data returned is for the first page
   "hasNext: true
}
```

with this, the service consuming your endpoint can keep making the call to fetch data while `hasNext` is true